# Where/How are the fonts configured in swaywm?

Tags: fonts, sway

Where/How are the fonts configured in swaywm?

I saw reference to `.Xresources`/`.Xdefaults` being used for some things https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sway#Xresources

What does `Xresources` handle if anything?

If Xresources is used for all of sway's font configuration, what values can be configured?

Is fontconfig https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/ the best way or even possible?

Comment: I assume that most applications still rely on XWayland, as they don't have native wayland support.  Therefore, it stands to reason that `.Xresources` or specifically`.Xdefaults` is still relevant.  Perhaps I misunderstood your question, though?

Comment: That is part of it. I was also wondering how to set the sway inteface fonts (window title bar, etc.), and how to set fonts for wayland stuff generally. About 50% of the stuff I have open at any time is running on wayland instead of xwayland.

Answer (score 7):

According to the man page 5 for sway

`man 5 sway`

You can set the font for the titles of windows and the bar command (probably for other things as well) using a line in your config. This is what I added to my

`~/.config/sway/config`

file

`font pango:SourceCodePro Medium 11`

I wanted to use the SourceCodePro font. Its package name on archlinux is

`adobe-source-code-pro-fonts`